# How do I expand and retract font size every second constantly?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, setinterval

I am attempting to animate some text. 
When the page loads I want this text to expand to a larger than default font size and then retract back to its original font size. I want this to happen within one second and to constantly do this.

This is what I have attempted so far, but doesn't work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function expandName(){
        nameInter = setInterval(function(){
            $("#name p").stop().animate({fontSize: '30px'});


            $("#name p").stop().animate({fontSize: '22px'});
        }, 1000);

    }
    expandName();
});
```

The html:

```
<div id="name"><p>name</p></div>
```

and CSS:

```
    #name p{
    font-size: 22px;

}
```

So I assumed that when the web page has loaded it will expand to 30px and retract to 22px every second and repeat this constantly. Why isn't it doing this?

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `callback` here:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function expandName(){
        nameInter = setInterval(function(){
            $("#name p").stop().animate({fontSize: '30px'}, function() {
                $("#name p").stop().animate({fontSize: '22px'});
            });
        }, 1000);

    }
    expandName();
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vva77/)**

Answer (score 1):

Most probably because you fire two animations right after eachother, and the second immediately stopping the first. So basically the first one (expanding the text) has a millisecond to animate, before it gets stopped already.

Try to call one function, and toggle between expanding and lowering the font-size in that function:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var animateText = function() {
        if($('p').hasClass('bigText'))
            var toSize = '10px';
        else
            var toSize = '30px';
        $('p').toggleClass('bigText');
        $('p').stop(true,true).animate({ 'font-size': toSize});
    };

    setInterval(animateText, 1000);
});
```

**EDIT**

I've added a pure css solution. The results are slightly different, but if you play a bit with the css animation options you can get it quite the same I believe. Check out the fiddle!

Basic css:

```
p { animation: textSizeToggle 1s infinite alternate; font-size: 30px; }

@keyframes textSizeToggle {
    from { font-size: 30px; }
    to { font-size: 10px; }
}
```

**[Fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/nyRPu/2/)**